# Angular 7 server side rendering while serve:ssr

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have installed the `@nguniversal/express-engine` and ran the below command
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr

Build is properly happening but while serve:ssr gives below error.

```
ERROR in ./dist/server/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.' in '<projectname>/dist/server'
 @ ./dist/server/main.js 96:17-29
 @ ./prerender.ts
```

Comment: Can you add your angular.json as well? Did you install using `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`?

Comment: Yes I have added that package.